# WEB IDE build - npm ERR! request to https://npm.sap.com

Tags: npm, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide, npm-registry

I have an SAP UI5 app that was last changed in 2018. When I pull the repository from Git and try to deploy it to SAPUI5 ABAP repository I am getting errors related to npm:

```
npm ERR! code CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
npm ERR! errno CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
npm ERR! request to https://npm.sap.com/@sap%2fgrunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build failed, reason: certificate has expired
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /mnt/npm_cache/_logs/2023-04-18T15_32_47_091Z-debug.log
```

I have already changed my local npm registry on my laptop, .nprmc file:

```
@sap:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I have tried to clear ui2 caches, browser caches. I don't know why its still pointing to npm.sap.com, there is nothing in my project that relates to npm.sap.com.

I have also tried to delete the gruntfile and package-lock.json and I was able to deploy. The code are now reflecting in SE80 BSP app but when you run in Fiori Launchpad, the changes are not reflecting in the system (as compared to WEB IDE test, changes are reflecting). So I think I really need to execute a successful build.

I have also tried the following links and for some reason I am still getting the same error:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build
- https://help.sap.com/docs/web-ide/sap-web-ide-full-stack/run-grunt-build
- https://help.sap.com/docs/web-ide/sap-web-ide-full-stack/updating-your-project-s-grunt-build-to-ui5-build

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all types of cache is cleared when deleting gruntfile and package.json:
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/03/02/cache-maintenance-in-fiori/

Comment: Good document but changes still doesn't reflect in Fiori Launchpad

Comment: It might be best if you focus on trying to build the project by eliminating any error messages and using UI5 tool instead of grunt as grunt is deprecated